# Node JS Webservice that redirects user to a certain URL after receiving request

Tags: node.js, angular

Trying to implement a really simple connection between 2 web application. In this case, I will use Site A and Site B for easy reference.

Site A

1. Implementing a simple method that opens a webpage and calls a SOAP OR REST webservice by Site B
2. Sends request with text "Site A request"

Site B Node JS

1. Receives request from Site B
2. If request contains text "Site A request", redirects user to page "www.SiteB.com"
3. If request does not contain required text, redirects user to page "www.google.com"
4. Will need to pass text "Site A" to Angular to allow www.siteB.com to display text "Welcome Site A"

Is such an implementation possible? If so, how do I perform the redirect from NodeJS?

Answer (score 2):

To make it easier.. i just redirected from the same server to different routes..

```
app.get('/redirect/:test', (req, res)=>{
    if (req.params.test == 'Site B request') {
        res.cookie("test", req.params.test, {
            maxAge: 1000
        });
        res.redirect(301, '/autologin/');
    }
    else {
        res.redirect(301, 'http://google.com');
    }
});

app.get('/autologin/', (req, res) => {
    let cookie = undefined;
    if(req.headers['cookie']){
        cookie = req.headers['cookie'].substr(5);
    }
    console.log(cookie);
    if(cookie){
        res.cookie('test' ,cookie, { maxAge: 9000,expires: 600});
        res.redirect(301,'/');
    }else{
        res.redirect(301, 'http://google.com');
    }
})
```

and as for angular code...
I used [ngx-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie) to use as cookie service..

```
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'app';

    constructor(
        @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object,
        private _cookieService: CookieService
    ){}

    ngOnInit(){
        if(isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)){
            let x:any = this._cookieService.getAll();
            if(x.test){
                this.title = x.test;
            }
        }
    }
}
```